# How to cast a date column value in javascript, and how to increase this date variable?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am using sharepoint 2013 online. I have created a custom list. On this list I have used JSLink to show an icon in a column. I would like to do some logic to show a red or a green icon. I have now in js 2 dates. The date from my column from the current item and the date of today. I would like to do the following check:

```
var contractEndDate = ctx.CurrentItem.Contract_x0020_einddatum;

    var today = new Date();


    if((contractEndDate + 10 days) > today)
    {
        return "<img src='https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/Sales/SiteAssets/green.png'/>";
    }
    else
    {
        return "<img src='https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/Sales/SiteAssets/red.png'/>";
    }
```

How can I cast the var contractEndDate to a date? And how can I increase it with 10 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 10 and compare:

```
var endPlus10 = new Date(contractEndDate);
endPlus10.setDate(contractEndDate.getDate() + 10);

if (endPlus10 > today) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by the [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. You can compute the number of milliseconds in a day (see one_day variable) and compare dates.

See my JS Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/cVm59/1/

```
var contractEndDate = new Date("2-18-2014"),
today = new Date(),
one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

if((contractEndDate.getTime() + (one_day*10)) > today.getTime())
{
    console.log("Less than 10 days ago");
}
else
{
    console.log("More than 10 days ago");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
var contractEndDate = ctx.CurrentItem.Contract_x0020_einddatum;

var today = new Date();

var CED = new Date(contractEndDate);
CED.setDate(CED.getDate() + 10);

if(CED > today)
{
```

Create CED as a new date and then using the setDate this just adds 10 days before you make your comparison.  You could clean this up and just set your contractEndDate as a new Date, but up to you.